# Modify/update file based on matching lines from another updated file - python

Tags: python, xml, file-handling

I have a file that needs to be modified (input.txt):

```
<sec name="M_14_K40745170" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz"/>
</sec>

<sec name="M_15_K40745171" so_fre="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGSH">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz"/>
</sec>

<sec name="M_16_K40745172" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907100" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz"/>
</sec>
```

By using the following updated file:

```
<sec name="M_15_K40745171" so_fre="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGSH">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz"/>
<xyz abc="trt" id="abc"/>
</sec>

<sec name="M_14_K40745170" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00"/>
</sec>

<sec name="M_16_K40745172" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907100" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
</sec>
```

I want to modify input.txt file by matching a specific/unique line which is similar in two files
for example

```
<sec name="M_16_K40745172" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907100" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
```

And extract lines before `</sec>` from updated file for every match line block to modfied input.txt file
for example  `<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>`
so that my modified input.txt looks like:

```
<sec name="M_14_K40745170" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00"/>
</sec>

<sec name="M_15_K40745171" so_fre="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGSH">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz"/>
<xyz abc="trt" id="abc"/>
</sec>

<sec name="M_16_K40745172" so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907100" tensi="SGCGSCGSCGS">
<mwan so_fre="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
</sec>
```

I am tring with follwoing logic psudocode:

```
with open('inputfile.xml', 'r') as file1:
    with open('updated.xml', 'r') as file2:
        
        for line1 in file1.readlines():
            for line2 in file2.readlines():
                if re.search('<sec name="M_\d+_\w+"',line1):
                    if re.search('<sec name="M_\d+_\w+"',line2):
                        if line1 == line2:
                            print (next(line2))
                            if line == '</sec>'
                            break
```

I am able to achieved the desired output by converting updated file into pandas data frame and use it to modify  input.txt file but the process is time consuming. Is there any efficient way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not clear or explicit what specific changes are needed and also there's no python code.

Comment: @LMC actually my files are big I have created these dummy files to keep it minimal anyways thanks for your suggestion. I will try to minimize it further.

Comment: It would be better to use `lxml` and `xpath` to find elements on both files. For example, this xpath expression: `//sec[@name="M_16_K40745172"]`

Answer (score 0):

To open the file for updating (reading and writing) use

```
open(file, mode='+')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

You can read lines untill you find the location to update

Edit:

If you know where the location to update is

`f.seek(offset, whence)`
To change the file object’s position

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects